# redux-persist failed to create sync storage. failing back to noop storage. What does this mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am a beginner and creating my first react-native mobile app. I have been stuck on this error and I don't understand what am I doing wrong here.
I will just provide all the code where I have used redux-persist for the sake of reference.

First is my store.js file where I am creating a store for my Redux implementation. It's a small file so I'll just provide all of it.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

//the reducer i implemented
import reducer from './reducer'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Now comes my App.js file:

These are the two libraries i have imported for the sake of my store:

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

import {store, persistor} from './redux/store'
```

My App class where i am rendering my main navigator:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    //contacts,
  }
render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <AppNavigator />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I debug my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your App.js is fine. Just like the imports in your store.js file. However I have no experience with the "storage" you imported, I have used [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) I recommend you take a look at this storage.

Now for debugging I recommend you use the [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native) tool, it has a Redux section for devices, although the installation is somewhat tedious, I am sure it will help you. You can guide yourself to implement it in your application [here](https://github.com/jk-gan/redux-flipper).